# Reading a .DAT file in python?

Tags: python

I am making a basic program that has a quiz with multiple choice answers. I want to access the data from the .DAT file. 
Here's the basic layout of the .DAT file.

```
Which sport uses the term LOVE ?
Tennis
Golf
Football
Swimming
A
```

How can I access each line separately?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading a binary .dat file as an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11798800/reading-a-binary-dat-file-as-an-array)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
for line in open(filename, 'r'):
    item = line.rstrip() # strip off newline and any other trailing whitespace
    ...
```

For the bonus: Tennis!

Comment: Sorry i'm quite new to python. What does the 'r' do? Thanks

Comment: 'r' tells `open` that you want to open the file as "read" as opposed to write, read binary, etc. see http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open