# Open .dat and .atr file types with Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to read in .dat and .atr files with Python; from Physionet, [these for example](https://www.physionet.org/physiobank/database/mitdb/). I've tried the standard context manager opening method:

```
with open("path/to/files/101.dat", "rb") as f:
  for line in f: print f
```

But I get uninterpretable results like `D"D ?C?C?C!?C?C?C?C?C` for the lines. These lines should be like `3.0000000e-003  4.9950000e+000  4.3400000e+000` (I know this from published studies with this dataset). Any ideas how I can read in this data?

Comment: I'd recommend digging in to these links: https://www.physionet.org/physiotools/wpg/wpg_toc.htm and https://www.physionet.org/physiotools/wag/

Answer (score 6):

You can try to open it [using `numpy`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11798898/5687152)

```
import numpy as np
myarray = np.fromfile("path/to/files/101.dat",dtype=float)
```

Comment: This can open file, but not in correct way

Answer (score 2):

To read a .dat file use the following code-

```
record = wfdb.rdrecord('../input/apneaecg/apnea-ecg/a01') 
wfdb.plot_wfdb(record, title='Record a01 from Physionet Apnea ECG') 
display(record.__dict__)
```

You need to have wfdb library installed for that.
The p_signal array in the above dictionary contains the ECG values for a01 person.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but this has worked for me:

```
data = np.genfromtxt('data.dat' , dtype=None, names=True, delimiter='\t')
```